# Importing a different python file in a different subdirectory?

Tags: python, pycharm

Say I have this "running" python file located in:

C:\folder\subfolder_first\running.py

And I have a "helper" python file located in:
C:\folder\subfolder_second\helper.py

I am using Pycharm and I want to run some of the functions/methods of the helper file in the running file. How do I do it?

```
from folder.subfolder_second import helper
```

I tried the above line, but it gives me the error message:
ImportError: No module named blah blah blah...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is \_\_init\_\_.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: Look at that duplicate. There is a link in there to the tutorial about Packages. Here it is too: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Ultimately, you need to pretty much place an `__init__.py` in the folder you want to make discoverable as a package to be able to import it. The material I provided will explain this well.

Comment: This answer would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python

Comment: @anon That's a completely different problem. That is misleading for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Python 3 only**

In order to get this to work youll need a file tree like this:

```
- folder
    __init__.py
    - subfolder_first
        running.py
        __init__.py
    - subfolder_second
        helper.py
        __init__.py
```

And then you would run `helper` from `running.py` like this:

```
from ..subfoler_second import helper
```

However, I would suggest structuring it like this instead:

```
- folder
    running.py
    - helpers
        my_helper.py
        __init__.py
```

Then import `my_helper` from `running.py` like:

```
from helpers import my_helper
```

The second way is much much better. Just do it like that.